# What's the best way to unwrap this?

Tags: uv-image-editor

Originally this was 6 different textures, but I combined the textures together and then manually positioned each UV to become seamless to achieve my desired result as seen here:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUNHF.png[1]

Here is another one where I haven't manually scaled and positioned each island.

The islands are all overlapped.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/wwiho7Z.png]

I'm trying to achieve the results of the first image. I've tried pinning all of the verts and then unwrapping but it just results in this: [image: https://i.imgur.com/bl8K90V.png]

Seams didn't work right either: [image: https://i.imgur.com/Nm3iL8P.png]

I also want to mention that clamp settings and constraining image to boundsd also didn't change anything.

Any ideas on how I can make each unwrap end up like the first? I'd rather not have to keep manually adjusting faces all over my scene.

Comment: If you have an un-triangulated version of that mesh, Unwrap with Active Quads would get you what you need

Comment: Thank you for your input this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll make an answer for it for posterity. ^_^

Comment: If you can find the time, mark the answer as a solution to your question, so it shows up as solved.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Follow Active Quads]

To get a **perfectly straightened unwrap** from quad-strips, the **Follow Active Quads** method exists.

This will take the selected geometry and **unwrap it as a rectangular strip, no matter what angle they have on the model**. It is particularly helpful on objects with even but somehow spatially warped surfaces, like pipes, floor maps, etc. and truly invaluable if you need 100% straightened unwraps. These often make texturing a lot easier.

It has two options for the Mapping Type:

**Even** will make all UV-Squares the same size,
**Length** will take the average length into consideration

To use Follow Active, select desired polygons. **Ensure that one of them is the Active Selection.** The algorithm will make this one the border piece in the unwrap. Also, as its name suggests, **it will not run without an Active Quad**.

Follow Active Quads has a couple of quirks, though:

For one, **it does not like Triangles or N-Gons**. It will split those from the quad strips.

For another, **if you have already unwrapped, the Follow Active Quads will sometimes give you skewed results**. In that case,

- select the strip you want,
- choose Unwrap > Reset
- with the same selection Unwrap > Follow Active Quads

Answer (score 2):

Enter the side view with numpad 1 or 3 (depending on your object's orientation). Hit U to get the unwarp options, and select "Project from View (bounds)".

These were my results: [image: UV map in the top left]

You can then manipulate the UV map to get rid of potential scaling issues.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, my objects aren't flat or orientated perfectly to face my camera. I would probably have to keep projecting it at different angles/distances until one looked decent enough to edit. Both results work though however the unwrap by active quad solution above was able to get what I needed with near perfect results.  I appreciate your input though!